# do sequelize associations do anything on the DB side

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

I've been using sequelize a lot in recent projects and I'm curious about what happens under the hood for associations vs migrations. For example, when I generate 2 models:

```
user = {
  id,
  name,
}
```

and

```
post = {
  id,
  name,
}
```

and then I generate a migration to add the associated columns:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'posts',
      'userId', // name of the key we're adding
      {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        references: {
          model: 'users', // name of Target model
          key: 'id', // key in Target model that we're referencing
        },
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
        onDelete: 'SET NULL',
      }
    );
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn(
      'posts', // name of Source model
      'userId' // key we want to remove
    );
  }
};
```

what does the `associate` method in the model do if the migration above adds the actual `userId` column to the posts table?

example of an `associate` method in a model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const post = sequelize.define('post', {
    name: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {});
  post.associate = function(models) {
    post.belongsTo(models.user);
  };
  return post;
};
```

which raises a bigger question, if the associate method ends up creating the actual foreign key column in the db, is an intermediate migration (like the one shown above, which creates the foreign key columns) necessary to create the foreign key column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TL;DR:** Sequelize `Associations` do not do anything on the DB side, meaning they can't (create tables, add columns, add constraints, ..etc)
>
> **Disclaimer:** I might've not covered all the benefits/differences of
>   both in this answer, this just an abstract.

1) here is how i differentiate the `Model` from the `Migration`
 (*based on functionality*):

- The `Migration` (creates tables, add constraints, ..etc) on the DB
- The `Model` makes it easier for you as a developer to interact with the table that corresponds with the `Model` (which is the model is defined for) on the DB, for example: A `User` model helps you to interact with the **Users** table without the need to write SQL queries.

2) The `Associate` methods give you two special powers which are **lazyLoading** and [eagerLoading](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#eager-loading) who both spare you the headache of doing `Joins` manually through raw SQL queries.
so yeah again: **"The Model spare you the headache of writing raw SQL queries yourself."**

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not fully answer the question in detail, [there's a decent description](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/associations/base.js) about associations in the sequelize github repo under the associations folder

The comment states:

> Creating an association will add a foreign key constraint to the attributes

also, the following hints at the fact that a column is actually generated from the association:

````
 * To get full control over the foreign key column added by sequelize,
 * you can use the `foreignKey` option. It can either be a string, 
 * that specifies the name, or and object type definition,
 * equivalent to those passed to `sequelize.define`.
 *
 * ```js
 * User.hasMany(Picture, { foreignKey: 'uid' })
 * ```
 *
 * The foreign key column in Picture will now be called `uid` 
 * instead of the default `userId`.
 *
 * ```js
 * User.hasMany(Picture, {
 *   foreignKey: {
 *     name: 'uid',
 *     allowNull: false
 *   }
 * })
 * ```
````